# Does installing ASP.NET MVC require a server reboot?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, installation, reboot

Does installing ASP.NET MVC **require a server reboot?**

I've set up quite a few ASP.NET MVC sites on production servers in my time, but today, I'm deploying to a server without MVC installed for the first time.

So, I installed the latest MVC release, restarted the IIS and went through the usual hoops to set up a MVC website on IIS6 (aspnet_isapi.dll, setting the correct .NET version, etc).

However, the site behaves exactly like a non-MVC website. The root url clearly maps to  default.aspx, but any controller/action urls all result in a 404.

I've had two colleagues check the site configuration, both giving thumbs up.

I won't reboot the server without a very good reason.
Does any of you know, whether I **need** to reboot after installation of ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: It might be worth asking the same question on serverfault.com.

Comment: I know it's a very old post. But i am facing the same problem. Could you please let me know what you did to resolve your problem of MVC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it doesn't (at least in Win2k8 x64, Win2k3 x64)

Kindness,

Dan